# No me funcionan las siguientes condicionales (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

Estoy haciendo este código pero realmente no sé porqué no me funciona, siempre que trato de definir las variables de los lados me aprece que el triángulo siempre es equilátero, ayuda!!!

```
    If ((lad1 = lad2) And (lad2 = lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un equilátero."
        PictureBox1.Visible = True
    End If


    If ((lad1 <> lad2) And (lad2 <> lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un escaleno"
        PictureBox3.Visible = True
    End If

    If ((lad1 = lad2) And (lad1 <> lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un isósceles."
        PictureBox2.Visible = True

    ElseIf ((lad1 <> lad2) And (lad1 = lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un isósceles."
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    ElseIf ((lad2 = lad3) And (lad1 <> lad2)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un isósceles."
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Cambia a este codigo, agrega todas la condicionales en un solo IF

```
 If ((lad1 = lad2) And (lad2 = lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un equilátero."
        PictureBox1.Visible = True
   ElseIf ((lad1 <> lad2) And (lad2 <> lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un escaleno"
        PictureBox3.Visible = True
   ElseIf ((lad1 = lad2) And (lad1 <> lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un isósceles."
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    ElseIf ((lad1 <> lad2) And (lad1 = lad3)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un isósceles."
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    ElseIf ((lad2 = lad3) And (lad1 <> lad2)) Then
        box1.Text = "Las medidas de su triángulo corresponden a un isósceles."
        PictureBox2.Visible = True
    End If
```